# Getting - The Operation Returned an error :0:You are not authorized! while pushing .nupkg file to Orchestrator using Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, devops, operation, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

Getting - The Operation Returned an error :0:You are not authorized! while pushing .nupkg file to Orchestrator using Azure pipeline

Created a Azure Pipeline.

Pushing to Default On-premise Orchestrator Instance

Comment: This is too less info. Please share some screenshots. Also tell use where you create the Azure Pipeline and what is the config of that. What did you try out th fix that already?